# How to SUM TIMEDIFF's During hours

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I hope this can clearly explain what I am looking for. I have searched read through a few articles on this site, but haven't found what I am looking for. I have also spent close to 3 hours trying to figure this out on my own.

I am trying to count the number of records and SUM the WorkTime. Here is my query I have been working with.

```
SELECT Log.User
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 0, 1, 0)) AS Midnight
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 1, 1, 0)) AS `1AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 2, 1, 0)) AS `2AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 3, 1, 0)) AS `3AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 4, 1, 0)) AS `4AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 5, 1, 0)) AS `5AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 6, 1, 0)) AS `6AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 7, 1, 0)) AS `7AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 8, 1, 0)) AS `8AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 9, 1, 0)) AS `9AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 10, 1, 0)) AS `10AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 11, 1, 0)) AS `11AM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 12, 1, 0)) AS `12PM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 13, 1, 0)) AS `1PM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 14, 1, 0)) AS `2PM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 15, 1, 0)) AS `3PM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 16, 1, 0)) AS `4PM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 17, 1, 0)) AS `5PM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 18, 1, 0)) AS `6PM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 19, 1, 0)) AS `7PM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 20, 1, 0)) AS `8PM`
 , if(hour(endtime) = 20, sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(endtime) - time_to_sec(starttime))), 0) AS `8PM Time`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 21, 1, 0)) AS `9PM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 22, 1, 0)) AS `10PM`
 , sum(if(hour(endtime) = 23, 1, 0)) AS `11PM`
FROM
  (
  SELECT user
   , controlnumber
   , starttime
   , endtime
   , timediff(endtime, starttime) AS Worktime
FROM
   atrtaxcert.ordertimeworked
  ) AS Log
GROUP BY
   Log.User;
```

These start and end times are only minutes apart.
Any guidance is much appreciated. This is my first post here, and was not able to provide any images to help describe.

Comment: currently is that query working ? Do you wanna optimize that  query ?
What is your exact requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If starttime and endtime are TIME datatypes, then use the TIME_TO_SEC function and do a subtraction.  Total up the seconds, and then convert the total to a string representation.

```
SELECT `Log`.`User`
     , ...
     , SUM(HOUR(`Log`.endtime)=20) AS `8PM_count` 
     , SUM(IF(HOUR(`Log`.endtime)=20,work_seconds,0) AS `8PM_seconds`
     , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(IF(HOUR(`Log`.endtime)=20,`Log`.work_seconds,0) AS `8PM_hhhmmss`
     , ...
  FROM ( SELECT
              , TIME_TO_SEC(endtime)-TIME_TO_SEC(starttime) AS work_seconds
       ) `Log`
 GROUP
    BY `Log`.`User`
```

---

NOTE: this:

```
SELECT HOUR(endtime)=0 AS foo
```

is shorthand equivalent to

```
SELECT IF(HOUR(endtime) = 0, 1, 0) AS foo
```

---

If `starttime` and `endtime` are DATETIME values, the you can use the TIMESTAMPDIFF function to calculate the difference in seconds:

```
SELECT `Log`.`User`
     , ...
     , SUM(HOUR(`Log`.endtime)=20) AS `8PM_count` 
     , SUM(IF(HOUR(endtime)=20,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`Log`.starttime,`Log`.endtime),0) AS `8PM_seconds`
     , ...
  FROM (
       ) `Log`
 GROUP
    BY `Log`.`User`
```

(You probably want to ignore the values returned when e.g. starttime = '23:59:00' and endtime = '00:01:00', and that would require another conditional test.)

Comment: Thanks for this. If only i tried awhile longer. Sometimes it just helps to step away. Just had to add "sec_to_time" at the very beginning to get back the time format